# C to MIPS conversion. Array load word offset?

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I have a C code that I need help with in MIPS. The C code is as follows.

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++){
   a[i] = b[i] + c[i] - d[i];
}
```

I have converted this to MIPS but don't know what to put into the offset of load word.

```
addi $t0, $zero, 0                #i = 0

for_loop:
   bgt $t0, 100, for_loop_done     #i <100
   addi $t0, $t0, 1               #i++ or i = i+1


   lw $t4, __($s0)              # load a in t4
   lw $t1, __($s1)              # load b in t1
   lw $t2, __($s2)              # load c in t2
   add $t4, $t2, $t1                 # add b with c and store in a
   lw $t3, __($s3)              # load d in t3
   sub $t4, $t3, $t4                 # sub contents of a from d
   sw $t4, __($s0)              # store contents of t4 into a

   j for_loop                     # go to start of loop

for_loop_done:
```

We assume that a,b,c,d are in s0,s1,s2,s3,s4 respectively. Now what the code needs is how we can offset the load word and store word with the ever changing 'i' from the c code. Because as far as I know load word only uses a static value.

Comment: you can increment s0,s1,s2...by the size of one array item each loop. Or make copies of them and increment those so you dont lose the original start address.  That works for most instruction sets including this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays are arranged with the lowest base address in memory and indexed to next element by an offset of 4 bytes.[Image from Harris D. M., Harris S. L. - Digital Design and Computer Architecture, 2nd Edition - 2012]

[image: Harris D. M., Harris S. L. - Digital Design and Computer Architecture, 2nd Edition - 2012]

```
 for_loop:
         bgt $t0, 100, for_loop_done     #i <100
         addi $t0, $t0, 1               #i++ or i = i+1


         lw $t4, 0($s0)              # load a in t4
         lw $t1, 4($s1)              # load b in t1
         lw $t2, 8($s2)              # load c in t2
         add $t4, $t2, $t1            # add b with c and store in a
         lw $t3, 12($s3)              # load d in t3
         sub $t4, $t3, $t4            # sub contents of a from d
         sw $t4, 0($s0)              # store contents of t4 into a

         j for_loop                   # go to start of loop

for_loop_done:
```